# Trying to make sense out of this Binary Search Tree in Leetcode. Number arrangement looks wrong

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree, computer-science, binary-search

This is a very general question

So I am doing some practice on leetcode.com with working with binary search trees. This doesnt make sense to me. The yellow highlighted 1 is on the right of the 2 but 3 is greater then 2 so shouldn't technically the 3 be on the right and the 1 be on the left ? If anyone knows anything about Binary Search Trees

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Here is the array order

[4,2,6,3,1,5]

Comment: Yes, that looks wrong if it's meant to show a BST. What's the link out of curiosity just in case some context is missing?

Comment: Ah, ya, I don't see any mention of it being a BST there. It's slightly confusing because it certainly *appears* to be one except for that one "mistake", but they seem to be just referring to a plain binary tree, which isn't necessarily "ordered" in any particular way.

Answer (score 3):

I think the question is just about a [Binary Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree), not the [Binary Search Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree), which in that case the left node does not need to be smaller than the right one, and these would pass.

#### Python

```
class Solution:
    def addOneRow(self, root, val, depth):
        sentinel = TreeNode(None)
        sentinel.left = root
        levels = [sentinel]
        for _ in range(depth - 1):
            levels = [child for node in levels for child in (node.left, node.right) if child]

        for node in levels:
            node.left, node.left.left = TreeNode(val), node.left
            node.right, node.right.right = TreeNode(val), node.right

        return sentinel.left
```

#### Java

```
public final class Solution {
    public static final TreeNode addOneRow(
        final TreeNode root,
        final int val,
        final int depth
    ) {
        if (depth == 0 || depth == 1) {
            TreeNode sentinel = new TreeNode(val);
            sentinel.left = depth == 1 ? root : null;
            sentinel.right = depth == 0 ? root : null;
            return sentinel;
        }

        if (root != null && depth >= 2) {
            root.left = addOneRow(root.left, val, depth > 2 ? depth - 1 : 1);
            root.right = addOneRow(root.right, val, depth > 2 ? depth - 1 : 0);
        }

        return root;
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-one-row-to-tree/discuss/) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.